# filtering a html table based on a condition entered in textbox javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a html table that displays student name and the number of leaves he has taken.how do i filter giving a constraint on the no of leaves and display it
,like if enter 5 in the text box,students with leave of 5 or more should be filtered and displayed.
the code i have now display the records with the entered value

```
    function myFunction1() {
        var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput1");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[6];
             if (td) {
                 if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                     tr[i].style.display = "";
                 } else {
                      tr[i].style.display = "none";
                 }
              }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd suggest you to have a look to dataTable plugin if jQuery is an option

Comment: This question would benefit from quality improvements. Your code indent is should be reworked and it's body (and title) is hard to read.

Comment: would a jQuery version be acceptable?

Comment: Your displayed filter block will match a string, and only a string. You are asking about a numerical comparison. See my suggestion, below.

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery version

```
var filter = $('#myInput1').val.toUpperCase();

  $("#myTable tr td:eq(6)").each( function() {
       var str = $(this).html().toUpperCase()
       if( str.indexOf(filter) > -1) 
         $(this).parent('tr').css('display','')
       else 
         $(this).parent('tr').css('display','none')
   })
```

Comment: I do love how concise jQuery makes things. However, this doesn't address the question (which his displayed function also fails to address): He wants a numeric comparison, displaying all results greater than the given input.

Answer (score 0):

quick knock-together that does what you're looking for, from what I can understand. I have also used the same filter function to allow me to screen by name or by student-year. It's a flexible filter routine, wish I'd taken the time to avoid hard-wiring the handling of strings vs numbers, but for your purposes, that'd be overkill, I think.

A strange gotcha with table rows: you can't simply display="none" and display="block" them, it garbles the table structure. That's why it's display="none and display="" below. A few sources pointed that out, and I'm glad they did. I was beating my head on that wall for a while...

Best of luck!

```js
// Store all the inputs...
var filterByName = document.getElementById("filter-by-name");
var filterByYear = document.getElementById("filter-by-year");
var filterByLeaves = document.getElementById("filter-by-leaves");
// And store the table itself.
var studentInfoTable = document.getElementsByClassName("student-info")[0];

// these functions will be called in the event listeners.
// By doing this, I only have a single filter function.
function byName() {
  var filterString = filterByName.value;
  filterBy("name", filterString);
};

function byYear() {
  var filterString = filterByYear.value;
  filterBy("year", filterString);
};

function byLeaves() {
  var filterString = filterByLeaves.value;
  filterBy("leaves", filterString);
};

/**
 * The filter function itself, accepts the field to filter
 *  by and the string to use as the filter data.
 *  In essence, we take each row of the body, find the td
 *  to filter by, compare that with the filter data itself.
 *  There are two types of compare: either text or numeric.
 *  
 **/
function filterBy(filter, filterString) {
  var selector = ".student-" + filter;
  var rows = studentInfoTable.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var filterEl = rows[i].querySelector(selector);
    switch(filter) {
      case "name":
        if (filterEl.textContent.indexOf(filterString) == -1) {
          rows[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
          rows[i].style.display = "";
        };
        break;
      case "year":
      case "leaves":
        if (parseInt(filterEl.textContent) >= parseInt(filterString) || filterString.length == 0) {
          rows[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          rows[i].style.display = "none";
        };
        break;
    }

  }
};

// The event listeners for each input.
filterByName.addEventListener("keyup", byName);
filterByYear.addEventListener("keyup", byYear);
filterByLeaves.addEventListener("keyup", byLeaves);
```

```css
.student-info {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.student-name {
  width: 40%;
}

.student-id,
.student-year,
.student-leaves {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="student-info">
  <thead>
    <td class="student-name">Name</td>
    <td class="student-id">S. Id</td>
    <td class="student-year">Year</td>
    <td class="student-leaves">Leaves</td>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="student-name">Abraham Abas</td>
      <td class="student-id">00141</td>
      <td class="student-year">2018</td>
      <td class="student-leaves">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="student-name">Billy Bragg</td>
      <td class="student-id">00143</td>
      <td class="student-year">2018</td>
      <td class="student-leaves">7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="student-name">Conor Chace</td>
      <td class="student-id">00147</td>
      <td class="student-year">2019</td>
      <td class="student-leaves">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="student-name">Daniel Daye</td>
      <td class="student-id">00150</td>
      <td class="student-year">2019</td>
      <td class="student-leaves">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="student-name">Edward Eppington</td>
      <td class="student-id">00151</td>
      <td class="student-year">2018</td>
      <td class="student-leaves">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="student-name">Frank Ford</td>
      <td class="student-id">00153</td>
      <td class="student-year">2020</td>
      <td class="student-leaves">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="student-filter">
  <h2>
  Filter by...
  </h2>
  <label>Name:
    <input type="text" id="filter-by-name">
  </label>
  <label>Year:
    <input type="text" id="filter-by-year">
  </label>
  <label>Leaves:
    <input type="text" id="filter-by-leaves">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Search Textbox:-

```
<label>Search:<input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" type="search" id="txtSearch" onkeyup="filter(this);"></label>
```

Script:-

```
 function filter(element) {
        var value = $(element).val();

        $("#DataTables_Table_1 tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this).text().search(value) > -1) {
                $(this).show();
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't post images of text on this site, post text instead when possible. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/5420829. Also you messed up the edit and your image wasn't visible [proof](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47108664/3). See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#images for how to properly insert images into posts. I rolled back your edit.